# Different / better approaches for calling python function from Java

Tags: java, python, jython, jpype, py4j

I am quite new to python and am trying to call python's function from java.

My primary requirements are these:

- call should be transparent, in the sense that it should not require modifying `.py` file simply to enable it to be called from java. I might be given any python file with some functions inside it. I should be able to call any of these functions without requiring to modify `.py` file.
- I want to be able to send arguments of both primitive types (`int`, `String`, `floats` etc.) or non primitive types (`HashMap`,`ArrayList`) from java to python function and receive back the returned object (which may of primitive types or non-primitive types) from python to java. I am also using pandas DataFrame and numpy ndarray and hence also want to be able to send and receive corresponding objects to and from java.
- I *preferably* want to stick to CPython instead of Jython because I might need to use newer libraries that might not be available in Jython.

There are several options that I found online. Few are:

- **Use Jython's [PythonInterpreter](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html)** with which I am able to invoke python function without requiring any changes to `.py` script file:

  **py1.py**

  ```
   def square2(list):
       squares = []
       for i in list:
           squares.append(i*i)
       return squares
  ```

  **JythonTest.groovy**

  ```
   import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter
   import org.python.core.*;

   class JythonTest
   {
        static main(def args)
        {
            PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter()
            pi.exec("from py1 import square2")
            PyFunction pf = (PyFunction)pi.get("square2")
            println pf.__call__(new PyList([1,2,3,4]))[2]   //9
        }
   }
  ```

  I am very well able to satisfy my needs. But its not CPython.
- **Use [ScriptEngine](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#jsr-223)**: This is very similar to PythonInterpreter. But agains its Jython. Also, unlike PythonInterpreter, we cannot work with Jython 2.5+ and cannot directly access PyObjects. So this option can be very well closed.
- **Use [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/index.html)**: Cant find example which is as minimal as in case of Jython PythonInterpreter
- **Use [java2python](http://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/)**. But [not much information is given](http://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/java2python.html) about calling python from java so that I can conclude whether my above requirements can be satisfied. Can anyone shed more light on this? More specifically if we can write the code as minimal as the one in Jython PythonInterpreter.
- **Use [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/)**: However after quick go through I feel I will not be able to write as minimal code as in case of Jython PythonInterpreter. Also I felt the project somewhat not under developement. Is it?

It seems that Jython PythonInterpreter is the best choice if I have understood all above approaches correctly. Have I made mistakes while grasping them? Also is there any other better option?

Comment: Not completely related, but is there any particular reason you would prefer to use CPython over Jython? Marshalling data types between Java and CPython is going to be more difficult and with Jython being built on top of the JVM interop should be way simpler.

Comment: because I feel Jython will be a bit slower than CPython, also may be because I may have to wait for some new libraries available in CPython but yet to come in Jython

Comment: I have never had any issues with Jython's performance in my use cases (may of course be different in yours). The library availability is of course a potential problem, however unless you know for sure that you need to use a library that is unavailable for Jython I think it's easier to use it instead of CPython. (It's what I usually did as I am unaware of any glue libraries that would enable the kind of interop you need)

Comment: Ok so u are of same opinion as mine that PythonInterpreter is the best way to go?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. (Unless, as mentioned, you absolutely need to use CPython)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current answer to this problem. Using CPython relies on the execution of Python bytecodes, which in turn requires that the Python interpreter be embedded in the execution environment. Since no Java runtime comes with an embedded Python interpreter, it really does look as though Jython is the best answer.

Sometimes the answer you want just isn't available!

Comment: Am revisiting this lately. I realized that I missed one more option: [jep](https://github.com/ninia/jep). Is it anything to look for? It seems that there is [no simple way](https://github.com/ninia/jep/issues/120) to deal with pandas dataframes using jep. Also it seems that we cannot obtain return values from python to java using jep. Is it so? Also my requirements in original post are changed a bit in that I need to send/receive pandas dataframe and numpy ndarray to/from java and python.

Answer (score 3):

@Mahesha999, regarding the ability to stick with CPython which seems important now from your last comment:

Jep is a good option to be able to run python code which uses calls to native, like pandas that you mentionned.

You'll need to write some wrapping code because Jep only implements automatic conversion between Java and Python between the most used types, which `pandas.DataFrame` is not.

However if your use case is not to complex, you can access your pandas objects as `numpy.NDArray` object by calling `DataFrame.values` on your dataframe instance, and Jep implement conversion to the Java class it embeds for NDArray.

You can get back to Java values from python code you execute by using `Jep.getValue(String pythonVariableName, Class clazz)`

For example

```
Jep jep = new Jep();
jep.eval("import my_script");
jep.eval("df = my_script.function_returning_a_dataframe()");
jep.eval("col = df.a_column.values");
NDArray myCol = jep.getValue("col", NDArray.class);
```

I do so on a project I coded in Python that I need to integrate as a plugin in a Java application, so far it works.